# Debugger is not working on Android Studio 4.2 Canary 15

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-debug

Since I installed Android Studio 4.2 Canary 15 I am not being able to debug my project.
I tried to perform debugging every way: using the menu, using the shortcut and even tried attach debugger but I had no success. I double-check my Gradle setting and Everything is looks fine and restarted `adb` many times.
Do you have any idea how to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly:

1- go to File then Invalidate Cache and restart

This restarts android studio without cache

Answer (score 0):

Just change windows Regional Format to English. Windows Settings -> Time & Language -> Region -> Regional Format . Then restart android studio

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30690400)